# Initialised ImageButton in other Activity throws nullPointerException when referenced in MainActivity

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, imagebutton, findviewbyid

I'm very new to Android and Java coding in general, so bear with me if I don't understand basic concepts.. This is just a test to see if something works, so It might not initially make any sense.

I have two activities, Main and Other. 
the Other Activity has an imageButton with visibility initially set to invisible.
When MainActivity is created, it should look for that imageButton in the Other activity, and set it's view to visible.

Though when debugging, all I get is a nullPointerException, because the button has null as value. How can I make it reference the button?

Part of Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pstep();
}


public void pstep() {
    int pstep = 0;
    ImageButton panfav = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.favpancake);
    panfav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Part of Other Activity:

```
public class navfav extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageButton panfav = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.favpancake);
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navfav);
}
    public void fab(View v){
    ImageButton panfav = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.favpancake);
    panfav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

XML linked to Other Activity:

```
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/favpancake"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="137dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:contentDescription="@string/nav_cook_dish"
    android:onClick="fab"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/dishpancake"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
android.widget.ImageButton.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void android.widget.ImageButton.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
at com.p2.rookie.MainActivity.pstep(MainActivity.java:23)
at com.p2.rookie.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
```

Shoot if I'm missing anything you need to use, I'll provide as much as i can :)
Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting nullPointerException because ImageButton with id favpancake is not present in MainActivity layout activity_main

```
public class navfav extends AppCompatActivity {

public static List<String> recipes;

// other code here

}
```

and then when you want to add recipe to shown in Other Activity listView,

```
recipes = new ArrayList<String>(); 

recipes.add(recipe);
```

Now when you open the other Activity all those recipes will be available in list name "recipes". which you can use to show in your listView.

Comment: And it makes total sense as well. But then how do I manipulate a View in a layout from a button in another layout? Fragments would be the way to go I guess? I'm just looking for the simplest solution available.. :)

Comment: what you wanna achieve actually?

Comment: In the Other Activity (one layout/page), I want to have a list of favorites for certain recipes. In MainActivity there should be a list of recipes with favorite buttons next to them. 

When pressing the favorite button in MainActivity on a recipe, that recipe should be shown in favorites list in Other Activity. 

Right now I'm just trying to hack something together to make it work with one recipe, having the same recipe invisible in favs until button press.

Comment: you can use list as static member  In the Other Activity to achieve that. Let me added my answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding your input!
Just read a bunch of other stuff elsewhere, and I think something made sense now! Instead of creating new intents and startActivity'ies when changing layout/pages, i just setContentView to new page, and gather all methods from different activities in one activity - That's how basic this fail was i think? ;) You get points for most elaborate answer though, and idea for list!

Comment: Uh, no, now all runs in one activity, but when I specify this in a method:

`ImageButton panfav = (ImageButton)` and then
`findViewById(R.id.favpancake);panfav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

- Then it still has panfav set to null :-( ?

Answer (score 1):

The visibility of the buttons are always "VISIBLE", please give me the log
and in the navFav activity the "fab" method are not in the onCreate

Comment: log posted, and second, do you mean i should put the code of the fab method in onCreate instead?

Answer (score 0):

One Activity can and should not reference elements in other Activities.

If you call 'setContentView' with a layout file, you can only reference the views in that layout file.

Try and tell us what you're trying to achieve and we might be able to help you out in improving your code.

Comment: Thanks for clarification - I've seen that in other questions, but then I think I'm misunderstanding the concepts of Activities.. 
Simply put, in the Other Activity (one layout/page), I want to have a list of favorites for certain recipes. In MainActivity there should be a list of recipes with favorite buttons next to them. When pressing the favorite button in MainActivity on a recipe, that recipe should be shown in favorites list in Other Activity. Right now I'm just trying to hack something together to make it work with one recipe, having the same recipe invisible in favs until button press.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Just read a bunch of other stuff elsewhere, and I think something made sense now! Instead of creating new intents and startActivity'ies when changing layout/pages, I just setContentView to new layouts/pages, and gather all methods from different activities in one activity - That's how basic this fail was I think? ;)

Then all views and methods can reference each other.